# Doesnt prompt anything , Signing a message with PRIVATE_KEY

Tags: function, digital-signature, smartcontracts, web3js, prompt

I am running this js file which creates a random value `Jeton` and wants to sign it only if two of a smartContract functions return true (if a certain conditions is met). The problem is when I try `node Signature.js` , my terminal doesnt prompt anything. Maybe it s due to the async function , and the `await` for the functions in the smart contract. (probably)
Here is my code :

```js
/*
Le signataire ne doit signer le message transmis que si les deux 
already_Signed_Addresses() et check_If_Address_Already_Signed()
sont vrais. 
Import le smart contract, call les deux fonctions, si elles sont just => ecrire code pour signer avec 
la private key d une addresse (Signgataire), si c est faux alors revert 
Ecrire une transaction du signataire au Citoyen (msg.sender), Avec comme data son Jeton signé
*/
const crypto = require("crypto");
const ethers = require("ethers");
const ABI = require("./abi.json");
const web3 = require("web3");
require("dotenv").config();

function getRandomJeton(Choix_Vote, N_V) {
  // Avoir deux nombre completement aleatoire
  let randomAnonymeNumber1 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  let randomAnonymeNumber2 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  // Avoir un nombre unique a chaque citoyen
  let uniqueNumber = "12345678910";
  // Mettre ensemble le nombre aleatoire et unique pour cree un nombre 100% aleatoire et unique
  let uniqueRandomValue = `${uniqueNumber}${randomAnonymeNumber2}${randomAnonymeNumber1}`;
  // Mettre ensemble les donne necessaire pour avoir le jeton
  let unhashedJeton = `${Choix_Vote}${uniqueRandomValue}${N_V}`;
  const Jeton = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(unhashedJeton).digest("hex");
  return Jeton;
}

const Jeton = getRandomJeton(1, 2);
console.log(Jeton);
//Function pour aveugle le jeton

const contractAddress = "0x2A6b9Dd8B2581FbCf2b8a54D6ACf278802C168E4";
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  `wss://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_PRIVATE_KEY}`
);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, provider);
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
// const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(PRIVATE_KEY);
// web3.eth.personal.newAccount("pierre").then(console.log);

async function sign_jeton() {
  if (
    (await contract.check_If_Address_Already_Signed()) == true &&
    (await contract.check_Database_Verified_Address()) == true
  ) {
    const signature_Jeton = web3.eth.accounts.sign(Jeton, PRIVATE_KEY);
    console.log(signature_Jeton);
    process.exit();
  } else return false;
}
sign_jeton();
```

I tried taking out the await and async function part and indeed it worked. So probably there is a mistake in the way i use this two keywords-functions :)

Any help would highly be appricated

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

web3.eth.accounts.sign doesn't need to be async/awaited. can you try seeing if anything prints from web3.eth.accounts.sign("", PRIVATE_KEY); with just an empty string? it seems to be working for me, as well what version are you using?

Comment: I tried taking away the ```async``` and ```await```but it still doesnt print anything apart from the ```console.log(Jeton)``` but it doesnt end the prompting and gets stuck.function
 ```javascript 
 sign_jeton() {
    if (
      contract.check_If_Address_Already_Signed() == true &&
      contract.check_Database_Verified_Address() == true
    ) {
      const signature_Jeton = web3.eth.accounts.sign(Jeton, PRIVATE_KEY);
      console.log(signature_Jeton);
      process.exit();
    } else return false;
  }
  sign_jeton();
  ```